# React native: execute code once after component loded

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When my app start, I load a component called ListComponent that will get all the items list from the server and show them is a listView. I have a sideMenu with different categories. If the user choose one category, ListComponent is called again through stackNavigator but with different URl. In `ListComponent` my code looks like

```
class ListComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
this.requestUrl(allItemsUrl)
}

componentWillUpdate(){
  const params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
if(params.id == '1'){
    this.requestUrl(urlCategory1);
  }else if (params.id == '2'){
   //.....
  }
}

render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <ActivityIndicator style={styles.activity}/>
        </View>
      );
    }

// show the list with the selected category data
```

`componentWillUpdate()` is called each time a new category is selected from the menu item. The problem is that when `componentWillUpdate` is called, the data is requested and then render is called again to render the new data, this will call `componentWillUpdate` again and create an infinite loop. But I didn't figured out what to use instead of `componentWillUpdate` to ensure that it will be called only one time when the category is selected from the `stackNavigator`.

**Edit:**

I stopped the infinite loop by applying the suggested solution in comments and comparing the old and nextProps. I also changed componentWillUpdate to componentDidUpdate but now I started getting a warning

> Warning: In next release empty section headers will be rendered. In
>   this release you can use 'enableEmptySections' flag to render empty
>   section headers

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: The whole lifecycle is there : 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html
Maybe check https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate
Apparently this is a good place for network calls

Answer (score 0):

You can compare props from `componentDidUpdate`. if category equal to old category will do no thing. edit from Dimitri Bosteels's answer

```
componentWillUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  const params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  if(prevProps.navigation.state.params.id === params.id) {
      return; //do nothing
  }
  if(params.id == '1'){
    this.requestUrl(urlCategory1);
  }else if (params.id == '2'){
   //.....
  }
}
```

Comment: I egt an error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nextProps.navigation.state.params.id')

Comment: i Just read Dimitri Bosteels's answer. Can you try `ComponentDidUpdate` instead of `ComponentWillUpdate`. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a component before `ComponentWillUpdate()` returns

See : [ComponentWillUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

But you can do it in [ComponentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) maybe?

Try to check these two links describing the lifecycle of a component.

Apparently, `ComponentDidUpdate()` is a good place to do networks calls.
Hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I did't it in ComponentDidUpdate() but when I had the problem I tried ComponentWilUpdate(). The problem is that when I make the REST request in ComponentDidUpdate() , than render is called and then ComponentDidUpdate() is called infinitely again

Comment: Then do as Giang Le said and use the version with prevProps, prevState of componentDidUpdate  and check if the state of params has changed. If not, do nothing so it won't trigger the next update